# Rotating a view using another view's center as the anchor point

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I have two image views. The first is the blueish arrow, and the second is the white circle, with a black dot drawn to represent the center of the circle.

[image]

I'm trying to rotate the arrow so it's anchor point is the black dot in the picture like this

[image]

Right now I'm setting the anchor point of the arrow's layer to a point calculated like this

```
CGFloat y = _userImageViewContainer.center.y - CGRectGetMinY(_directionArrowView.frame);
CGFloat x = _userImageViewContainer.center.x - CGRectGetMinX(_directionArrowView.frame);
CGFloat yOff = y / CGRectGetHeight(_directionArrowView.frame);
CGFloat xOff = x / CGRectGetWidth(_directionArrowView.frame);

_directionArrowView.center = _userImageViewContainer.center;

CGPoint anchor = CGPointMake(xOff, yOff);
NSLog(@"anchor: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(anchor));

_directionArrowView.layer.anchorPoint = anchor;
```

Since the anchor point is set as a percentage of the view, i.e. the coords for the center are (.5, .5), I'm calculating the percentage of the height in arrow's frame where the black dot falls. But my math, even after working out by hand, keeps resulting in .5, which isn't right because it's further than half way down when the arrow is in the original position (vertical, with the point up).

I'm rotating based on the user's compass heading

```
CLHeading *heading = [notif object];

// update direction of arrow
CGFloat degrees = [self p_calculateAngleBetween:[PULAccount currentUser].location.coordinate
                                            and:_user.location.coordinate];


_directionArrowView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((degrees - heading.trueHeading) * M_PI / 180);
```

The rotation is correct, it's just the anchor point that's not working right. Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Comment: `_directionArrowView.center = _userImageViewContainer.center;` how can both of these be the same? directionArrowView.center will be a point above `_userImageViewContainer.center` right?

Comment: You're right. I think this line might be counterproductive to what I'm doing. Maybe if my auto layout constraints can line them up correctly, it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always found the anchor point stuff flaky, especially with rotation.  I'd try something like this.

```
    CGPoint convertedCenter = [_directionArrowView convertPoint:_userImageViewContainer.center fromView:_userImageViewContainer ];

     CGSize offset = CGSizeMake(_directionArrowView.center.x - convertedCenter.x, _directionArrowView.center.y - convertedCenter.y);
 // I may have that backwards, try the one below if it offsets the rotation in the wrong direction..
//  CGSize offset = CGSizeMake(convertedCenter.x -_directionArrowView.center.x , convertedCenter.y - _directionArrowView.center.y); 
     CGFloat rotation = 0; //get your angle (radians)

     CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-offset.width, -offset.height);
          tr = CGAffineTransformConcat(tr, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation) );
          tr = CGAffineTransformConcat(tr, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(offset.width, offset.height) );


    [_directionArrowView setTransform:tr];
```

NB.  the transform property on UIView is animatable, so you could put that last line there in an animation block if desired..

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but it's crashing because of auto layout: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`. I'll play around a bit and see if I can fix the constraints to work with this

Comment: turn em off and use UIViewAutoResizingMask for these two views..  Sometimes auto layout is too clever for its own good on iOs (its awesome in cocoa, where it's really needed..)

Comment: I just got this working. For the offset, I didn't user the `convertedCenter`, but instead compared the centers of both view's in the superview's frame: `CGSize offset = CGSizeMake(_userImageViewContainer.center.x - _directionArrowView.center.x, _userImageViewContainer.center.y - _directionArrowView.center.y);` Thanks for the help man

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better use much easier solution - make arrow image size bigger, and square. So the black point will be in center of image.

Please compare attached images and you understand what I'm talking about

New image with black dot in center

[image]

Old image with shifted dot

[image]

Now you can easy use standard anchor point (0.5, 0.5) to rotate edited image